# Multiple GOLANG functions in one global function

Tags: go

I'm new in programming and also with GOLANG! I was wondering if there is a possibility to put few functions in one global. for example, if I have 3 function which gives me 3 different fmt.Println output and if there is a way to put they together in one instead of run hello(), hello1(), hello2().

example code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    hello()
    hello1()
    hello2()

}

func hello() {
    fmt.Println("example 1")
}

func hello1() {
    fmt.Println("example 2")
}

func hello2() {
    fmt.Println("example 2")
}
```

I hope this make sense...

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what exactly your question is? It might be helpful if you could share the code you have (you can [edit] your question).

Comment: added an example code

Comment: For those who put downvote on this question - the person is new to SO and to programming. Instead of putting downvote - you can try to spend some time and answer the question or ask for additional info or just ignore it. It's not so kind of you to just put downvote and scare the person on his first steps into world of programming.

Comment: thank you @Vusal! this was exactly my thought. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "one global function". Does it mean that instead of making individual calls to the 3 functions, you need a wrapper, which in-turn calls these 3 functions?

Comment: yes I mean exactly this @windstorm

Comment: No one who can help me even a yes or no answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    funcs := []func() {
        hello,
        hello1,
        hello2,
    }

    for _, f := range funcs{
        f()
    }

}


func hello() {
    fmt.Println("example 1")
}

func hello1() {
    fmt.Println("example 2")
}

func hello2() {
    fmt.Println("example 2")
}
```